# Texify crashes after Miktex update

Tags: pdftex, texify

Today I ran the update on my MikTeX 2.9 install  on Windows.

After the update, the following started to happen: if I run `texify` on my document (a MWE consisting of the bare preamble and a single word in the document), the compilation runs fine (I can see it completed in the `log`) but `latex.exe` crashes (reported by Windows) before `texify` returns; similarly, `pdflatex.exe` crashes after the compilation is completed when run by `texify --pdf`. The issue disappears if I run `texify` from an elevated account.

Both `latex.exe` and `pdflatex.exe` compile my document without crashes if I run them on their own, even as a regular user.

I have checked the regular user's permission in the most obvious places. I have run `initexmf --dump` both as admin and as a regular user. Same with "update formats" in Settings. I also checked the `log` file as produced by `pdflatex` standalone and when called by `texify`; the only difference is that when called by `texify`, full paths are used for all the files.

PdfLatex version:

`MiKTeX-pdfTeX 2.9.5700 (1.40.16) (MiKTeX 2.9)
Copyright (C) 1982 D. E. Knuth, (C) 1996-2014 Han The Thanh
TeX is a trademark of the American Mathematical Society.
compiled with zlib version 1.2.8; using 1.2.8
compiled with libpng version 1.6.17; using 1.6.17
compiled with poppler version 0.32.0
compiled with jpeg version 8.4`

Any idea what else I could check?

Comment: Welcome! It uses the same versions either way? Does `texify` have something like a `--debug` or `--verbose` option? (Note that I know zilch about Windows so maybe options work differently there. But hopefully you'll know what I mean, even if I don't.)

Comment: Yes, I did reboot. For this tests I'm using the command line to avoid a hidden parameter or something from the environment (I usually use WinEdt). So, I type `texify b.tex`, it compiles and at the end Windows says that latex.exe crashed. If I type `latex b.tex` or `pdflatex b.tex` it compiles with no issues. If I run an elevated prompt, `texify b.tex` compiles without crash.

Comment: Yes, I ran the update for both the regular user and the admin user. Same with the other attempts I mentioned above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I found the issue. My command line was using the system-wide `pdflatex.exe` from `Program Files`, while `texify.exe` was using the version in the user's `appdata\roaming` folder. I just copied the exe from the global folder to the local one, and the error disappeared.

The binaries were not identical, although they both reported to be the same version.

Comment: THANK YOU!!  I have been bugged by this issue for a whole month without getting an answer!!! Wow!

Comment: Glad I could help.